# How to make the hybrid the default map on Google maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Google Maps just made the API exactly like the real thing. So now I want the map to display the hybrid map by default, I looked all over [Google's Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/controls.html#DefaultUI), but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try the [constructor](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMapOptions)?

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), { mapTypes:[G_HYBRID_MAP] });
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
map.setUIToDefault();
```

Comment: This does work, but it will make the hybrid map the only option.

Comment: Ah I see... using the mapTypes option like that would normally make the hybrid map the only option, but setUIToDefault overrides it.

Answer (score 3):

you can also pass the map-type with

```
map.setCenter(point, zoom, G_HYBRID_MAP);
```

Answer (score 3):

For the V3 API you can set the default map type in the map options:

```
map.setOptions({
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To make hybrid the default map, try this:

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
map.setUIToDefault();
map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
```

Here's the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.setMapType).

Answer (score 0):

map.maptype = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID

mMap.maptype = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).